# How can i change kivy window position

Tags: python, kivy

**Is there any other way to change window position without using:**

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 100)
Config.set('graphics', 'top',  100)
```

*I don't want to use this* because when i change the last parameter (`100`) with my property it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

<s>It's possible with the current master branch that has [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4851) change.</s>

Update: It's possible with the current Kivy stable version → `1.10.0`.

With that you can access the `Window.top` and `Window.left` properties and change `Window` position at runtime as well as get the actual position of the `Window`. Without that change (e.g. version 1.9.1), there's no way how to do that.

Also, `Config` is basically for a *single* change before the application actually runs e.g. set the position to [0, 0] and the Window will display at that position after `App().run()`. Nothing more really.